# I'm having trouble deserializing a Boolean data

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net, postman

I present my case:

I have a JSON file with X information with this field (which is what I'm having trouble with)

```
{
.........
  "isUrgent": true,
.........
}
```

In VS Professional with c# and .net Core I have the following code

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RegisterObject
{
.........
[JsonProperty("isUrgent", Required = Required.Always)]
        public bool IsUrgent { get; set; }
..........
}
```

Through postman, I send my JSON to the VS Proffesional solution.

```
{
.........
  "isUrgent": 100,
.........
}
```

I send a JSON that contains any numeric (we are testing) and the system converts it to Boolean, specifically to the value true, giving the system as valid.

I hope you can help me :)
Thanks and regards.

Comment: You can check ModelState.IsValid in your controller to ensure that passed parameters are correct

Comment: I have added this property in my controller and the ModelState.IsValid appear as true. This conversion happened before reaching the controller...
My problem is that I dont know why this happens :(

Comment: That's built in behaviour of Newtonsoft.Json. It will also accept strings "True" or "False" as booleans. I believe there is no built-in way to disable this behavior so you have to write a custom converter for bool type and register it.

Comment: You can follow this issue on github
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16884
It's the thing you are looking into

Comment: When you assign IsUrgent a value other than true/false, the ModelState.IsValid will be false. IsUrgent property will always have a default value as it is a non-nullable type. Other options you have is to use CustomAttributes or implement IValidatableObject.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @PradeepPrabhu I have tried to use this option but It didnt work. People say that it's problem of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson libreries.

Comment: I think that this post is resolved. We can close it :-)

Answer (score 1):

As [Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14202100/denis) said:

> You can follow [this issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16884) It's the thing you are looking into.

It's a library problem. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: And also [Support "strict mode" for RFC7159 parsing #646](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/646).